# Providing multiple implementations for templated function tackling a particular type each time

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a comparator for strings. However I want it to work for both strings and char*s. 
Something like `StringComparer<std::string, std::string>` and `StringComparer<const char *, const char*>`. Of course, inside the implementation for `Stringcomparer<const char *, const char *>` I will simply do a `std::string Stringversion(<pass the const char* here>)` for both strings and simply call the `Stringcomparer<std::string, std::string>`.

How can I write two such templated functions for my Stringcomparer.

I have been looking for this and all I can find everywhere are examples where people have defined a function like this:

```
template <typename T> foo(T&)
{
    //some operation on T that does depends on operators or functions that can handle any //type like sort or cout. basically there are showing that this fucntion can be used to sort //both integer and string vectors or it can cout both integers and floats.
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can provide multiple variants of my stringcomparer. Surely there are times when people need to write a separate routine handling each type. How is this accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a primary function template and the [fully] specialize it for different types, e.g.:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&);                 // primary template declaration
template <> void foo<std::string>(std::string& s) { // specialization for std::string
    // ...
}
template <> void foo<char*>(char *&s) {             // specialization for char*
    // ...
}
```

Note that the specializations have to match the primary template with the specialized type replaced exactly! In general, I find it easier to specialize class template implementing function objects (i.e., have a function call operator) and delegate to these from a general function template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template specialisations. Here is a short example.

```
template <typename T> 
void foo(const T& arg)
{
    // code
}

// Specialises the function template for char*
template <> 
void foo(const char*& arg)
{
    // different code
}
```

EDIT: Oops, specialised for string to start with.

Comment: Why not just overload? And what about non-standard `basic_string`s?

Comment: @KerrekSB Better to ask the OP!

Comment: @KerrekSB I cannot use overload since I am writing code for already existing codebase where it expects templated functions. (a test suite is already implemented) Can you please explain your query about "non standard basic_strings"

Comment: @Wildling: `basic_string` is a template, and `string` is a specific specialization of it. It would be more natural to fit make a function that fits *all* basic_string specializations (and uses the character traits for comparison).